# Dynamic layout selection in grails 3

Tags: grails, sitemesh

With [sitemesh](https://sitemesh.org) possible to use different layout for same pages. For example for mobile and PC users

But how to do this with grails?
In [documentation](https://gsp.grails.org/latest/guide/layouts.html) and [article](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2011/03/grails-goodness-applying-layouts-in.html) nothing about this case written
I have tried tag in view.gsp, not working

```
<meta name="layout" content="${defineLayout()}"/>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any dynamic expression to express the name of the layout.  For example...

```
<meta name="layout" content="${someVariable}"/>
```

That expression could reference model variables, or session attributes or request parameters, etc.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/demon101dynamiclayout.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/demon101dynamiclayout/blob/a383176ccc728a93a05a365638149dde8c548737/grails-app/views/layouts/plain.gsp

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <title>
        <g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/>
    </title>
    <g:layoutHead/>
</head>

<body>

<H1>This Is A Plain Ole Layout</H1>
<g:layoutBody/>

</body>
</html>
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/demon101dynamiclayout/blob/a383176ccc728a93a05a365638149dde8c548737/grails-app/views/demo/index.gsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="${dynamicLayout ?: 'main'}">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/demon101dynamiclayout/blob/a383176ccc728a93a05a365638149dde8c548737/grails-app/controllers/demon101dynamiclayout/DemoController.groovy

```
package demon101dynamiclayout

class DemoController {

    def index() {
    }

    def plain() {
        render view: 'index', model: [dynamicLayout: 'plain']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By grails code exploration I have found GroovyPageLayoutFinder class
it has line

```
final Object layoutAttribute = request.getAttribute(LAYOUT_ATTRIBUTE);
```

I can just put **org.grails.layout.name** attribute to request in Interceptor. It works like a charm!